# Is it possible for hacker to decrypt the password of Laravel project easily using Laravel decryption method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, password-protection, password-encryption

No doubt Laravel is a classy and strong framework. I'm a beginner. As I know Laravel's encrypter uses OpenSSL to provide AES-256 and AES-128 encryption. My worries is- if someone has get access on my database and collected my encrypted password. As I have used the Laravel inbuilt Encryption method, isn't it possible to decrypt that password by that hacker. If the encryption and decryption method are discussed in Laravel Documentation, then I think it is possible. Please let me know it is possible or not?

Comment: passwords should be stored with salt + hash, not encryption.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel's passwords are not encrypted, they are hashed - see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing. It's two completely different techniques - hashing and encrypting.

- Encrypting is reversible. Laravel offers built-in encryption for stuff you would like to store safely and be able to decrypt later.
- Hashing is done one way. Nobody - not you, not systems administrator, not hacker can decrypt passwords from the user table. You can only brute force - you can try different passwords one by one, hash them and compare hashes.

Comment: then how Laravel define and matched the hashed password when I'm trying to log in.

Comment: @MosharofHossain The hash method do it. An simple way to see it, it's to get your password enter in your login form, Laravael count the number of characters in it and comparte to the Hash in your DB (which contains also the number of characters in this exemple). If it's the same number the user is log but same if you have this hash (example "12") you can't get the password without hash. 
This is an example, the real Hash method is really more complexe

Comment: @MosharofHossain when you try to login, Laravel receives your entered plain-text password (password you entered in the form), then it hashes it using the same hashing algorithm and compares the result to the one in the database - if two hashes match, it's assumed that two source strings (passwords) were the same too. It's the most common way to protect passwords today